# Do I have a problem of endogeneity?

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

I'm currently writing a dissertation on the impact of microfinance activity in a country on the poverty headcount ratio. It's a panel data model where i = country and t = year. I would like to finalise my model and know what variables are endogenous before I choose between a fixed/random effect estimator.

My measure of microfinance activity is the gross loan portfolio of all the microfinance institutions (within a country) scaled per capita.

Currently my model is set out as follows:

Poverty Headcount Ratio = a + B1GrossLoanPortfolioperCapita + B2GDPperCapita + B3CommercialBankandOtherLending + B4GrossNationalExpenditure + B5LifeExpectancy + E

Firstly, is there anything else you could suggest I control for? I've thought about including inflation, inequality (GINI coefficient), corruption index, time taken to start a business etc. Are there any key ones I'm missing out? Some are more relevant than others and the more I include, the more insignificant the variables above become.

Secondly, I would like to know what variables are endogenous? I feel like there may be some reverse causality between microfinance activity and poverty but I'm not sure what else. I'm also struggling for good instruments for microfinance activity.

Lastly, I've been deliberating whether or not to lag some of my variables like GDP per capita. Would this be recommended?

You'll probably ask why I'm doing my dissertation on this, I'm now considering the same question but it is too late to change. Any help is really appreciated. I apologise for the simplistic nature of the question to more experienced statisticians.